# Eager loading not working in EF

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-4

I am pulling out my hair, I have no idea why I can't return the AdPhotos and Location entities. I am using .ToList() shouldn't it keep the AdPhotos collection intact?

When I place a breakpoint on the return, I can see the data in AdPhotos and Location but after that it disappears.

```
public List<AdListing> LatestAdListings()
{
    using (var db = new AdultdirectoryEntities())
    {
        var results = (from a in db.AdListings.Include("AdPhotos").Include("Location")
                       join l in db.Locations on a.LocationID equals l.LocationID
                       where a.Approved && l.CountryID == Constants.ItemKeys.UsCountryId && a.AdPhotos.Count > 0
                       orderby a.CreateDateTime descending
                       select a).Take(5).ToList();

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: On this page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) I read "When you call Include, the query path is only valid on the returned instance of ObjectQuery. Other instances of ObjectQuery and the object context itself are not affected."

I think this is my issue, does anyone have a better solution for returning the full relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Include` call is followed by manual join - that is not supported. Once you use manual join or projection you are changing shape of the query and all `Include` calls are lost.

Moreover you don't need the join because you can write the query like:

```
var results = (from a in db.AdListings.Include("AdPhotos").Include("Location")
               where a.Approved && a.Location.CountryID == Constants.ItemKeys.UsCountryId && a.AdPhotos.Count > 0
               orderby a.CreateDateTime descending
               select a).Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped. I have one more question. What about if id like to do on another relationship within the "Location" relationship, how do I perform this?